# Parser server installation on my local mac.Complete guide from first step to last

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, parse-platform, server

I want implement parse server on my local for the development of ios app with it.But I don't know how install it locally and use it.I need a complete guide from installation to first line of code of ios app.

I have tried it's installation with official parse guide.but it needed mongodb, python,express and etc.I am unable to understand how to use these with parse server.So Please help me with a complete step by step guide.

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might not be reading the question right, but let me know if this helps.

Just use the auto install on heroku (https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example) and click on the the 'deploy to heroku' button.  It will create the parse server for you and your mongodb for you.

Steps that I took
1.) Sign up for heroku
2.) Click 'deploy to heroku' from this link: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example
3.) deploy it
4.) update your parse app keys

You could also use nodechef.com (paid), they manage the creation of the parse server and all that stuff for you.

Comment: I have used these steps and working fine but Got new solution from same guide thanks'